# Dynamic Rendering in Angular8

Tags: angular, express, pug, angular8, angular-universal

Requirement is to be render the style dynamically as per configuration in server.

Example:

```
    Path :/customer?customerId=1

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="customer1.css">

    /customer?customerId=2

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="customer2.css>
```

I was decided to follow the angular-universal approach which helps me to render html on server-side by querying server configuration.

```
app.get('/customer:customerId', (req, res) => {
  console.log("hello");
  // console.log(pug)
  res.render('index', { req, styleDet : 'customer1' });
});
```

`styleDet` is the dynamic content that should be injected to index.html but that is not working.

I was moved to another approach to use template engine using pug.

Installed pug in dev dependencies:

```
npm install --save pug
```

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import * as express from 'express';
import * as pug from 'pug';
import {join} from 'path';

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');

// // * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
// const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} = require('./dist/server/main');

// // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
// app.engine('pug', ngExpressEngine({
//   bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
//   providers: [
//     provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
//   ]
// }));

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', 'src');

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  console.log("hello");
  // console.log(pug)
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

This is resulting module not found error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'pug'
    at webpackEmptyContext (/Users/boopathi/Documents/Projects/Angular-Universal/ssr/dist/server.js:17271:10)
    at new View (/Users/boopathi/Documents/Projects/Angular-Universal/ssr/dist/server.js:17162:38)
    at Function.render (/Users/boopathi/Documents/Projects/Angular-Universal/ssr/dist/server.js:12379:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/boopathi/Documents/Projects/Angular-Universal/ssr/dist/server.js:24813:7)
    at /Users/boopathi/Documents/Projects/Angular-Universal/ssr/dist/server.js:143:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/boopathi/Documents/Projects/Angular-Universal/ssr/dist/server.js:15833:5)
    at next (/Users/boopathi/Documents/Projects/Angular-Universal/ssr/dist/server.js:14754:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/boopathi/Documents/Projects/Angular-Universal/ssr/dist/server.js:14729:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/boopathi/Documents/Projects/Angular-Universal/ssr/dist/server.js:15833:5)
    at /Users/boopathi/Documents/Projects/Angular-Universal/ssr/dist/server.js:14229:22
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ssr",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compile:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",
    "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run ssr:server:production --bundleDependencies all"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^8.2.6",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "v8.2.6",
    "@types/pug": "^2.0.4",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.24",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.24",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue or suggest me any other approach that is more feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind including the style in the build, you could add the different styles to the `styles.scss` file.

**styles.scss**

```
//common rules go here
//...

//customer specific rules below

body.customer1{

// ...rules for customer 1
}

body.customer2{

// ...rules for customer 2
}
```

Then, in your app component or whichever component where you know the customer, dynamically add the corresponding class to the body element.

**component.ts**

```
import {DOCUMENT} from "@angular/common";
import {Renderer2} from '@angular/core';


constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any, private renderer: Renderer2)
{
}

//add this when you subscribe to route change, or ngOnInit
this.renderer.addClass(this.document.body, 'customer1');//or customer2
```

**Alternative**

You could also directly add the correct css link in your component based on the current customer. However, with that approach, I dont' think that the css will not be inlined when you load the page, so display might be a bit slower

```
const link = this.renderer.createElement('link');
this.renderer.setAttribute(link, 'rel', 'stylesheet');
this.renderer.setAttribute(link, 'href', 'customer1.css');
this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.head, link);
```

Comment: styles are dynamic which i retrieve from server and that should be send to component. Need a clue how to send from server.ts to component

Comment: Well that's the alternative solution then

Comment: Alternative solution is which you suggested or anything different?

Comment: The one I suggested. You can load the css file from the server by adding dynamically the link element

Comment: Well, How to inject the link from server to component? any clue for this.

Comment: Do you mean that the name of the file is not customer1 or customer2 like in your example?

Comment: yes, Its single file. Need to render once in browser since its customer dependent.

Comment: Thats what I'm showing in the example. In your component you know whether it's customer 1 or 2 or whatever (based on the routing or other). Based on that knowlege, just dynamically add the css file link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211421/discussion-between-boopathi-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ThemeComponent` with `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and treat all styles in this component like global styles. Then, you can put this component anywhere in your app and use `*ngIf` to conditionally apply those styles. Create a different `ThemeComponent` for each different set of styles you want to change dynamically.

Comment: How to inject value from server to theme component? Is there any example?